# Adding multiple intent filters to MainActivity doesn't work

Tags: android, android-activity, filter

I have MainActivity on which I am adding multiple intent-filters, with a purpose to open the MainActivity.

But the problem is that onNewIntent() is called but intent.action is always main, even when it should be VIEW_RICH_PUSH_MESSAGE. If I remove the second intent filter and add that to another new Activity, it will work for that Activity.

What I want is to define multiple intent filters for one Activity but I couldn't figure out the problem.

My manifest is defined as follows:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.urbanairship.VIEW_RICH_PUSH_MESSAGE" />
            <data android:scheme="message"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    
    </activity>
```

What can I try next?

Comment: do you want all properties work in one activity ?

Comment: "but it never calls onCreate() method" -- if the activity already exists, you will get the new `Intent` via `onNewIntent()`.

Comment: @Syed Hamza Hassan because I want based what I receive as notification navigate to fragments of MainActivity.
but if I have another activity(ReceiveActivity) and if I want to navigate to MainActivity which has already existed it means I am creating new instance of MainActivity , am I right , that is why I want to keep in one MainActivity

Comment: can't get what you want ? Please describe in points.

Comment: I have 2 reasons. but if I am wrong please correct me
1.My start point(launcher) is MainActivity if I am turning the settings killing activity and when my application is not active opening notification it navigates to MainActivity.
2.If I the activity (MainActivity) is created and if I am declaring these actions in ReceiverActivity and when I open the notification it means it opens ReceiverActivity which navigates to MainActivity.
It doesn't mean that if we navigate to MainActivity we are creating another instance of MainActivty by calling startActivity()

Comment: @CommonsWare if the activity is created I will get new Intent via onNewInent() and do all the actions in onNewIntent() but if the activity has already killed onCreate is called, so I should listen to push notifications in both places in  onCreate() and in onNewIntent(), yes?

Comment: Yes. For example, you could put your handle-the-incoming-`Intent` logic in a separate method, which you call from `onNewIntent()` and `onCreate()` as appropriate.

Comment: yes, I am doing that way, Thanks.

Comment: @CommonsWar
onNewIntent() when I am checking the intent.action it returns ...action.Main while I am opening the push notification message.
so it hasn't solved yet

Comment: You need to look in the `Intent` object passed to `onNewIntent()`. `getIntent()` returns the `Intent` that was used to create the activity instance.

Comment: Thanks it works
I was thinking if in Fragment we can do getArguments() why I can't do getIntent in Activity, I was using getIntent() in onNewIntent() .
Thanks again